# Realtek 2800 wireless card DISABLED while not shown as blocked

Tags: wireless, realtek

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my desktop, but when I start up the computer the wireless doesn't work. I know this is a popular question, I did a search and people seems to have trouble with software/hardware block, or driver issue... But none of them seems applicable to me.

If I click on the network icon at the top right corner, it shows wireless as "disconnected" but it doesn't list available networks. If I uncheck/check the "Enable Wireless" option to reset, the option will stay as "disabled". If I uncheck/check the "Enable Networking" to reset the network interface, then the wireless shows as "device not ready".

If I run sudo rfkill list all, wireless shows as soft blocked: no and hard blocked: no.
If I run lshw -C network, wireless shows as DISABLED, and driver shows as rt2800pci.
If I run nm-tool, there are no wireless access points listed.

Thus I know my wireless card has a proper driver, it is not soft/hard blocked, and my desktop shouldn't have any hardware switch...

So what other steps I can go to trouble shoot this issue??

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Can you add the information from the link I just gave you to the question so we can confirm it is indeed the realtek card?

Comment: @JorgeCastro Thanks for your kind reply, sadly I don't have a cable nearby and thus my desktop relies on wireless network... I'll have to copy/past the output and transfer them in some kind of media. I'll post the info once I have the chance!

Answer (score 0):

I too had similar problem and sorted it of my own ubuntu is a great operating system  to play with. ok coming to business. Follow these steps:

1. Go to Applications >> Accessories >> Terminal
2. Type `sudo lshw -short`.

Now it will display all the hardware components including networking ports attached to the system mostly it should be a broadcom device which is used for wlan.

And the funniest part is to check whether you have switched on the wi-fi, because the messages about wireless connection displays only if the drivers for the wi-fi is installed so check for the user manual for your laptop and go through how to switch on the wi-fi in your laptop?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sujith, but mine is a desktop so I don't think there should be any hardware switch.